# Jason Keban – posted a CSS alternative to using image maps

Tags: html, css

It works really well, but not so well in Safari or iOS mobiles. When you leave the hover state it does not return to the original state. In other browsers it does.

His CSS was;

```
.hotspot {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
.hotspot + * {
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0;
}
.hotspot:hover + * {
opacity: 1.0;
}
.wash {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

and his html was;

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 188px; width: 300px;">
<img src="http://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg">
<div class="hotspot" style="top: 50px; left: 50px; height: 30px; width: 30px;"></div>
<div>
<div class="wash"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">A</div>
</div>

<div class="hotspot" style="top: 100px; left: 120px; height: 30px; width: 30px;"></div>
<div>
<div class="wash"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">B</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help fixing this and only using CSS would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no hover on touch devices, you're either touching an element or you're not.** Sometimes your `:hover` state may be triggered by the touch event itself - which is why you can't leave that state as there is no mouse-out.

One solution would be to disable the `:hover` style for touch devices and using the `:active` styles instead.

You’ll need to detect if the user is using a touch device. There is no reliable way to do this in CSS. There are JS solutions such as [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) but you really need to research the problems with detecting touch devices. Sure, the user might have a touchscreen but perhaps they’ve got a mouse plugged in. See [Stu Cox's article about this](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/). It's old but still relevant.

Anyway, I digress. Back to your question:

```js
if ('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints) {
  document.body.classList.add('touch');
} else {
  document.body.classList.add('notouch');
}
```

```css
.hotspot {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.hotspot + * {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.notouch .hotspot:hover + * {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
.hotspot:active + * {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
.wash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; height: 188px; width: 300px;">
  <img src="http://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg">
  <div class="hotspot" style="top: 50px; left: 50px; height: 30px; width: 30px;"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="wash"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hotspot" style="top: 100px; left: 120px; height: 30px; width: 30px;"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="wash"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With `:active` pseudostate it can be done without any javascript. However this is the good answer. My upvote

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude agreed (and thanks for the vote), the `:active` pseudo is the fix however the OP has found that some touch devices are triggering the hover state ontouchstart too but that the state remains because there's no blur/mouse-out happening. The JS part is purely to solve the problem of the hover declaration being matched for touch devices but you're right, the `:active` pseudo is the real hero here.

Comment: Thanks both for looking into this. I have tested it on MacOS Desktop, iPad and iPhone devices and got a mixed bag. 

MacOS Desktop; Chrome, Firefox worked well, but they did anyway, Safari worked with the hover/active, but didn’t return to the original state like it did in the others. Both iPad and iPhone didn’t work at all.

I need to check my interpretation of the statement and code as I couldn’t test the code snippet on the iPhone so had to create my own versions of the file. I will get back to you, but not sure if you are seeing the same results as I am.